# Swift currency-style without zeros

Tags: swift, number-formatting

I'm using CurrencyStyle number formatter. It produces output like "$ 521.00". Is it any simple way to remove trailing .XX without writing custom number formatter?

I want output like "$1,521" without trailing zeros.

```
var asCurrency: String {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        if let formattedPrice = formatter.stringFromNumber(self) {
            return formattedPrice
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to print the amount without fractional digits generally
then you can set

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
```

For `1521` you will then get the string `$1,521`. Non-integral values
are rounded, so for `1234.56` this will produce the string `$1,235`.
The rounding behavior can also be controlled with the `roundingMode`
property.